# Creating a re-usable API for creation / maintenance of Joomla accounts for use in Android App / Mobile Site development

Tags: android, joomla

I am using Joomla 1.5 and I am already aware of some of the difficulties associated with creating Joomla accounts from third party domains and scripts and authenticating with Joomla (logging in) from a third party domain / script.

My understanding is that the difficulty lies in the usage of a secret key to salt the MD5 hashed password for added security, and that this key resides in the configuration.php file.

That once Joomla 1.5 is installed, in configuration.php we already have a secret key in the form of:

```
var $secret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
```

Now assuming that we have access to the **jos_users** and **jos_sessions table**, is it not possible to create a simple PHP script (that given the Username, Password, MD5 hashed and salted using the secret key) that we could use to bypass Joomla completely and handle signup, login, logout and session data directly via the MySQL database without the need to touch the Joomla installation at all?

I would like to do this by creating an /api folder as a project and build on this platform.

I have much to learn I know, but I am hoping, logically, a reusable piece of code can be constructed.

If not,I understand that perhaps a simple plugin maybe needed to help facilitate these features using XML-RPC from within the Joomla Framework, however I would prefer to avoid this route.

Comment: What would be the point of bypassing the joomla security? Are you really planning to rewrite the joomla functionality from scratch from a different web folder? PS: I'm not a Joomla user/developer, so perhaps, I may be misunderstanding what you're trying to do. Personally, I've used Drupal and an api module to create a ready-made Drupal api for Android (I'm surprised Joomla doesn't have something like that already, have you looked?).

Comment: From what I have been able to establish from the available extensions there is nothing that handles authentication from a third party client / domain. I can create a mobile version of my Joomla site from various available extensions, however none of these cover what I need to do. The mobile framework I am looking to use (built in HTML5 JQuery Mobile) is too complex in itself to integrate into Joomla directly as a component / mobile template. And so this will run from a sub-domain, and the ios and Android Apps will be native (I think).